# Omnet++: Separate cQueue for each input

Tags: c++, queue, omnet++

I have a simple module with a `cQueue queue;`, which I use to queue incoming messages in `handleMessage()`: `queue.insert(msg);`

Now I extended my module to have an array of inputs `input in[]` and I want to queue incoming messages in separate cQueues for each input.
I thought I could simply initialize `cQueue queue[];` or `cQueue queue[gateSize("in")];` and then use `msg->getArrivalGate()` in `handleMessage()` to select the right queue.

Unfortunately, I already get errors for the initialization: `field has incomplete type`. Any help or suggestions?

Comment: Add a line `debug-on-errors=true` in your `omnetpp.ini`. Then debug your simulation. IDE will show you the line of code, which causes exit of simulation. Ref: [OMNeT++ Manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:run-sim:debugging-support)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `gateSize()` doesn't work in the class declaration. Also, I need to declare the `cQueue` array with a certain size. Thus, I just assumed that I have at most 10 inputs at each of these module objects (or choose any other number) and created an array of fixed size: `cQueue queue[10];`. If there are less than 10 inputs, some of the queues are just unused.

This is probably not the best solution, but it works. I tried using `std::vector` dynamically add queues during `initialize()`, but it didn't work.